# Using Python, upload image on https://cloud.google.com/vision/ and read JSON script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, automation, urllib2

I want to write a python script to automate uploading of image on https://cloud.google.com/vision/ and collect information from JSON tab there. I need to know how to do it.

Till now, I'm only able to open the website on chrome using following code:-

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://cloud.google.com/vision/'

webbrowser.open_new_tab(url + 'doc/')
```

I tried using urllib2 but couldn't get anything.

Help me out please

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use google-cloud-vision lib
there is a sample code in this docs
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

you can start from here